# The direct limit of $A_{f}$ for $f \notin P$ is $A_{P}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity, and $P$ a prime ideal of $A$. I want to show that $\lim_{f \notin P} A_{f} = A_{P}$. $A_f$ is the localization of $A$ at $\{1\} \cup \{f^{n}: n \in \mathbb N\}$, and $A_P$ is the localization of $A$ at $A \setminus P$. There is a natural map from $A_{f} \to A_P$ if $f$ is not in $P$, so by the universal property of the direct limit, we get a map from $\Phi : \lim_{f \notin P} A_{f} \to A_{p}$. Then it remains to show that this canonical map is an isomorphism. Surjectivity can be proven just using the universal property without knowing what $\Phi$ looks like. However I cannot prove the injectivity using the universal property. It seems that one has to use the explicit form of $\Phi$ in order to achieve that.

Comment: Think geometrically, in $\text{Spec} A$, $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is the stalk at $\mathfrak{p}$, $A_f$ for $f\notin \mathfrak{p}$ is the global section of $D(f)$ and all such $D(f)$ is a neighborhood basis at $\mathfrak{p}$, hence $\lim_{f \notin \mathfrak{p}} A_{f} = A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

Comment: Have you tried using the universal property of $A_P$ to get a map going in the other direction?

Comment: Thanks for answering but not quite sure that I understand what you mean. I guess one of the purposes of this statement is to prove that the stalk of $SpecA$ is $A_{P}$. Of course that depends on how you define the structure sheaf. @YangPei

Comment: No I haven't, but wouldn't universal property will always give a map pointing out from the direct limit?@RichardD.James

Comment: @penny No, the universal property of localization states that if $\varphi: A \to B$ is a ring homomorphism such that $\varphi(S) \subseteq B^\times$, then there is a unique induced homomorphism $\widetilde{\varphi}: S^{-1} A \to B$ making the appropriate diagram commute. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)#Universal_property).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you're assuming the direct limit exists, but justifying that requires some sort of explicit construction anyway, which you're trying to avoid.

I think what you really what you want to do is to show that $A_P$ (with the system of natural maps $\phi_f \colon A_f \to A_P$) satisfies the universal property in question, using only the universal property of localization.

For that, suppose we have $Y$ with natural maps $\psi_f \colon A_f \to Y$. We need a unique map $u \colon A_p \to Y$ where $\psi_f = u \circ \phi_f$. Fix $f \not\in P$. For all $g \not\in P$, the map $\psi_f \colon A_f \to Y$ factors through the map $A_f \to A_{fg}$, and $g$ is a unit in $A_{fg}$, so $\psi_f(g)$ is a unit in $Y$. Hence there exists a unique map $u_f \colon A_P \to Y$ such that $\psi_f = u_f \circ \phi_f$.

All that's left is to show $u_f$ is independent of $f$, which is essentially formal. Write $\alpha_{f,g} \colon A_f \to A_g$ (when this makes sense). For all $f, g \not\in P$,
$$\psi_f = \psi_{fg} \circ \alpha_{f, fg} = u_{fg} \circ \phi_{fg} \circ \alpha_{f, fg} = u_{fg} \circ \phi_f.$$
By the uniqueness of $u_f$, we have $u_{fg} = u_f$. Hence $u_f = u_{fg} = u_{gf} = u_g$.

Comment: Elements and explicit constructions are overrated ;)

Comment: @user714630 Hmm, yes, though I think abstract nonsense can be overrated too. How do people actually *think* about localization? As fractions. How do people actually *think* about this result? As allowing more and more elements in the denominator until you allow all of them, which makes it obvious. My argument completely elides this intuition, making something simple opaque to most people. On the other hand, the abstract perspective assures us these notions are "important" or "fundamental" and assures us we've found the key insight in the localization construction. So, both are useful :).

Comment: I was joking, but there's never a bad time for philosophizing about math!

Comment: Thank you, and you are right one does need explicit construction to show that the direct limit exits. It is just that it seems hard to try to recall that construction every time I need it. Do you by any chance know of any references that has an explicit construction of this particular direct limit?

Comment: @penny As far as an explicit construction of this direct limit, well the argument I ran through says that $A_P$ qualifies, so plug in any explicit construction of $A_P$. The standard definition of $A_P$ is in terms of fractions. You can also see it as a subring of the [total ring of quotients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ring_of_fractions) of $A$, which is a generalization of the field of fractions of an integral domain. Under that identification, this direct limit is literally the set-theoretic union. I'm getting the sense you're getting lost in abstraction--try working some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Take an element $\xi$ of the kernel of $\Phi$, represented by $\frac a{f^n}$ for some $f\not\in P$. We know that $$\frac a{f^n}=0\quad\text{in the ring $A_P$}$$whence there exists $g\not\in P$ such that $ga=0$, so that $$\frac a{f^n}=\frac {ag^n}{(fg)^n} = 0\quad\text{in $A_{fg}$}$$This means that $\xi=0$ (in $\varinjlim A_f$).

Comment: Why an element in the direct limit must be of the form $\frac{a}{f^n}$?

Comment: @penny: Firstly, there is a surjective map $\bigoplus_{f\not\in P} A_f\to \varinjlim A_f$ that comes from the canonical maps $A_f\to \varinjlim A_f$ (this may not be clear, or this may be part of the definition you are using for direct limits). So, $\xi=a_1/f_1+\dots+a_m/f_m$ (replacing any instance of $f^n$ with $f$). Because we have maps $A_{f_i}\to A_{f_1\dots f_m}$, we may as well use $\xi = b/f_1\dots f_m$, combining the fractions.